# how to make url "category/product/'

Tags: django-rest-framework

I started to study django rest framework and would like to understand how to get the url structure right. At the moment, I could only figure out how to do it by slugs, but I can’t figure out how to do it by category / product
serializers.py

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Category
        fields = ('id','url','name','slug')
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'id', 'url', "name", "slug", "category", "price",
              "photo", "description")
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }
```

views.py

```
class ProductAPIList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['name', 'description', 'category__name']

class CategoryAPIList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset =  Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['name']
```

And urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'product', ProductAPIList)
router.register(r'category', CategoryAPIList)
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/',  include(router.urls))
]
```

Comment: Please write your expected URL, like `localhost:8000/api/v1/xxx/yyy/<id>/`

Comment: localhost:8000/api/v1/video-cards/rtx-3060

Answer (score 1):

you should use multiple lookup fields in URL

```
router.register('(?P<category__slug>[^/.]+)', ProductViewSet)
```

and in your viewset:

```
class ProductViewSet(MultipleFieldLookupMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_fields = ['category__slug', 'slug']

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(**self.kwargs)
```

Note that I used a `Mixin` called `MultipleFieldLookupMixin` which is not part of DRF itself
and you should write it manually:

```
class MultipleFieldLookupMixin:
    """
    Apply this mixin to any view or viewset to get multiple field filtering
    based on a `lookup_fields` attribute, instead of the default single field filtering.
    """
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()             # Get the base queryset
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)  # Apply any filter backends
        filter = {}
        for field in self.lookup_fields:
            if self.kwargs[field]: # Ignore empty fields.
                filter[field] = self.kwargs[field]
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter)  # Lookup the object
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj
```

Here is more detail about this `Mixin`:
[MultipleFieldLookupMixin](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#creating-custom-mixins)